# spacing between \paragraph{} and next chars

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

Is it possible to make a new line between the text of \paragraph{} and the next characters ? I've tried this, but nothing have changed.

```
\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Rechercher \fg}
\newline
Comme décrit dans le tablea
```

Thanks in advance !

[image]

Comment: try `\hfill\newline` if it's for just one instance.  if it's throughout your document, then gonzalo's answer is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `\paragraph`, changing the negative length for the fifth argument of `\@startsection` and using a positive appropriate length:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\alph{paragraph}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {0.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation}
Some text for the paragraph text for the paragraph text for the paragraph text for the paragraph text for the paragraph text for the paragraph

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The same can be obtained with the help of the `titlesec` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\alph{paragraph}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.5ex}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation}
Some text for the paragraph text for the paragraph text for the paragraph text for the paragraph text for the paragraph text for the paragraph

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]