# No line gap between \paragraph{} and text

Tags: spacing, errors, line-breaking, overleaf, paragraphs

I have used all of my `\subsection{}` headers so using `\paragraph{}` with `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}` and `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` in the contents. The subheading is showing up just fine but the text of that paragraph begins just after that subheading, not on a new line. I have tried but \ and the `\newline` command but it just comes back with `latex error: there's no line here to end!`.

Comment: paragraph is defined as a run-in heading in `article` class (you have not said which class you have) it is easy to change to a display heading

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427836/create-new-subsubsubsection-in-custom-class-file/427844#427844

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155493/1090